# Is it possible for a secondary view to resize automatically within a storyboard as "view as" changes?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I've got a view controller with a secondary view, which looks like this in the storyboard when viewing as an iPhone 7

[image]

But if I switch to view as iPhone SE it looks like this:
[image]

Is it possible to get it to resize itself automatically within the storyboard in the same way the view controllers do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do what you described.

The [device configuration pane](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev44ecfa876) automatically adjusts the layout of `ViewControllers` only -- not `UIViews` alone.

If you would like to preview what your custom UI component will look like in different devices, I strongly suggest subclassing `UIView` and using `@IBDesignable`, `@IBInspectable`. You would also create a `XIB` file that layouts the design of your "widget".

This way you can use your custom component in Interface Builder just like any other view, and preview it using the above **device configuration pane**.

For example: let's say I have two custom components, one is a simple question with a switch button, the other one is a component to "lock/unlock" a credit card. Both rely on `XIB` files and `UIView` subclasses:

> Custom component 1

[image: xib01]

> Custom component 2

[image: xib02]

I can now use those in Interface Builder as any other view, inside any View Controller:

[image: IB]

And finally (now getting to your question), we can live preview how it will look like on different devices using the **device configuration pane**:

> 4S preview

[image: preview4s]

> 7+ preview

[image: preview7+]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... well first what are you trying to accomplish? I have never added a view to a view controller in that way. Based on the title of that UIView it looks like you are trying to have a custom view handle errors. Here is a (not as in-depth as it needs to be) quick preview of "Constraints With Visual Format" / `NSLayoutConstraint`'s in code.

Make a class called `MyCustomView` (or what ever) and have it inherit from UIView. Then in your UIViewController you can add it when ever you need using constraints with visual format.

1) Initialize and configure your `MyCustomView` when ever you need to present it (This code is somewhere inside your view controller):

```
let alertView = MyCustomView(frame: CGRect(0,0,200,150))

self.view.addSubview(alertView)

alertView.constrainToSuperView()
```

2) This is what the `constrainToSuperView` looks like in your custom class:

```
private func constrainToSuperView() {

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    let vertical = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[self]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["self": self])

    constraints.append(contentsOf: vertical)

    let horizontal = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[self]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["self": self])

    constraints.append(contentsOf: horizontal)

    self.superview.addConstraints(constraints)

}
```

There is a tone to learn about managing constraints in code but it's a worth while trick. It helps you create custom views and keep storyboards a little cleaner.

Note 1: I have added zero content to the `MyCustomView` class. It will present a blank view right now. You have two options for adding content. Fist, you can continue down the road of writing constraints in code or you can add a .xib file and create the internals of this custom view there. The second way is probably the way to go.

Note 2: You can always add a custom view in storyboard and then create an outlet for its constraints. You could then animate its constraints to move the view off screen and on screen when ever you need to present it.

Let me know if you have any questions. I would be happy to expand my answer.